# Access 2010 VBA loop not adding data rows to table

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

This database will be the death of me...I'm trying to take results in a form and copy the data into a table. I created a button to hopefully do this, but all it does is open the table with no data. The data I need to see in the table can be in the hundreds to thousands of records. This is what I have so far:

```
`Private Sub Command42_Click()

Dim db As Database
Dim rec As Recordset

Set db = CurrentDb
db.Execute "Delete * FROM Import70_TBL"
Set rec = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Import70_tbl")
Do Until rec.EOF
    rec.AddNew
    rec("CCAMPUS") = Me.CCAMPUS
    rec("FUNCAFF") = Me.FUNCAFF
    rec("BUILDING") = Me.BUILDING
    rec("ROOM_NO") = Me.ROOM_NO
    rec("BLDG_NAME") = Me.BLDG_NAME
    rec("ROOMCD") = Me.ROOMCD
    rec("ASF") = Me.ASF
    rec("STATIONS") = Me.STATIONS
    rec("FAC_DEPT") = Me.FAC_DEPT
    rec("PGM_CODE") = Me.PGM_CODE
    rec("CCPEC") = Me.CCPEC
    rec("CCLSIZE") = Me.CCLSIZE
    rec("CRESIZE") = Me.CRESIZE
    rec("NSFDISC") = Me.NSFDISC
    rec("AREA_UNITS") = Me.AREA_UNITS
    rec("BUILDING_ZIP_CODE") = Me.BUILDING_ZIP_CODE
    rec.Update
Loop
rec.Close

DoCmd.OpenTable "Import70_tbl"

End Sub`
```

Obviously, I'm doing something wrong, but I can't figure it out. Thank you in advance for anyone that can help me.

Comment: Are you sure you hit the refresh button? New records don't show automatically if the table is already open.

Comment: `Do Until rec.EOF` basically means "do these actions for every record in the recordset".  However your recordset contains no records because you deleted them from the table 2 lines earlier.  Therefore the `Do ... Loop` code is not run, which means no record is added.  If you intend to add just one record, discard the `Do Until rec.EOF` and `Loop` lines.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. I actually need all the rows of records from the form to be added to the table. The reason why I added the loop or thought I needed the loop was when I hit the button it only added the first row shown in my form. To answer your question Tom, there was no data in the table before I started.

Comment: I even tried to removing the loop. I still cannot get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the *RecordsetClone* of the form:

```
Private Sub Command42_Click()

    Dim db  As DAO.Database
    Dim res As DAO.Recordset 
    Dim rsc As DAO.Recordset 
    Dim fld As DAO.Field

    Set db = CurrentDb

    db.Execute "Delete * From Import70_tbl"
    Set rec = db.OpenRecordset("Import70_tbl")
    Set rcs = Me.RecordsetClone

    Do Until rcs.EOF
        rec.AddNew
            For Each fld in rcs.Fields
                res.Fields(fld.Name).Value = fld.Value
            Next
        rec.Update
        rcs.MoveNext
    Loop
    rec.Close
    rcs.Close        

    DoCmd.OpenTable "Import70_tbl"

End Sub
```

Comment: thank you! I will give this a try, and let you know if this works.

Comment: I'm getting an error code 438 object doesn't support this property or method. This what I've listed for each field,         'rec.AddNew
            For Each fld In rcs.Fields
                res.Fields("CCAMPUS").Value = fld.CCAMPUS
            Next
        rec.Update
        rcs.MoveNext'; do I have this wrong?

Comment: Sorry I didn't give you the info. The error is at 'res.Fields("CCAMPUS").Value = fld.CCAMPUS'

Comment: Try with `fld!CCAMPUS.Value`.

Comment: Thank you. I will give this a try, and let you know if this works.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I get the same error on the same row. This is what i have listed: Do Until rcs.EOF
        rec.AddNew
            For Each fld In rcs.Fields
               fld!CCAMPUS.Value = fld.CCAMPUS
            Next
        rec.Update
        rcs.MoveNext...also, I'm trying to list this as a code for you, but I'm having difficultly, sorry.

Comment: Well, do use my modification. Also, the field names of the two tables must match exactly.

Comment: The field names of the two tables matches. I decided to start over again. so I copied the code. Then deleted the event procedure on the form, and then re-added the procedure again. Now I'm getting a new error it's Compile error: Variable not defined at Set rec = db.OpenRecordset("Import70_tbl"). The highlight is on 'rec'.              I would like to chat, but I don't have enough points to move this to a chat. Just a stupid question, am i supposed to add this under each new field: Next
        rec.Update
        rcs.MoveNext
        rec.AddNew
            For Each fld In rcs.Fields

Comment: I did. `Private Sub Command42_Click()

    Dim db  As DAO.Database
    Dim res As DAO.Recordset
    Dim rsc As DAO.Recordset
    Dim fld As DAO.Field

    Set db = CurrentDb

    db.Execute "Delete * From Import70_tbl"
    Set rec = db.OpenRecordset("Import70_tbl")
    Set rcs = Me.RecordsetClone

    Do Until rcs.EOF
        rec.AddNew
            For Each fld In rcs.Fields
               fld!CCAMPUS.Value = fld.CCAMPUS
            Next
        rec.Update
        rcs.MoveNext
        rec.AddNew
            For Each fld In rcs.Fields` ...for all my field

Comment: I decided to create an append query, then run a macro. It seems to work. Thank you for all your help. My fear was that there is too much going on with other codes...maybe this couldn't work.

Comment: rsc and rcs is not the same. You have to pay attention to the details, or coding will represent a continuous challenge.